# Fortify unable to load build session with ID when scanning iOS project

Tags: ios, load, fortify

When scanning iOS project using Fortify, we are facing "unable to load build session with ID" issue.

What I did was, I opened the project by pointing to the folder of the source code. Then this error happened.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same error while building a project written in C++. I am using VS 2017 and Fortify is throwing this error while running Analyze solution on .sln file. 
Maybe this is occurring because of trying to translate and run -show-build-warnings in one command.
-show-build-warnings is a separate step, and will only work after translation, so try your command without that switch. 
If it completes successfully, then you can run from VS dev cmdprompt sourceanalyzer -b  -show-build-warnings to check for warnings.
You can check 'not show warning as errors' and reduce warning level to W3 and then build the solution in debug mode.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by first doing the equivalent of a "make clean". If there are already executables there, sourceanalyzer make -s will no op and Fortify will not be able to work with them.